# Horror movie with a boy swapped at birth whose biological parents are both murderers

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie on TV 20 years ago.

**Prologue:**

A mad woman trades a baby in his cradle with her own newborn. She is charged by police for murder and imprisoned in a psychiatric hospital. The newborn scratches with his "mother's" face with his nails.

**Years later:**

The newborn is a boy, and is silent, sad and shy. He is bullied by some students, and an unidentified killer kills one of the bully boys with a shotgun shot to the head. The killer then hides in the attic of the silent boy's home.

**Conclusion:**

The mother of the boy discovers he is not her real son and investigates to discover that the real mother of her "son" is a murderer and her biological son is in a orphanage. When she returns to her home and discovers the killer of the bully, who is also the father of the boy and husband of mad killer woman, at her house. He tries to kill her but the silent boy defends his adoptive mother and shoots the man who is actually his father.

**Happy end:**

The biological son and the adopted son live together happily in the new family
with mother and father.

**Details:**

This likely came out between 1989-93, it was probably a made-for-TV movie from the USA.

Comment: I think this was asked here before but I can't find it. A very detailed question, anyway. Posting a possible match.

Comment: I don't know a possible match

Comment: I meant **I** was posting it. ;) Look below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're after the horror movie [Relative Fear](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110965/combined) (AKA The Child) from 1994.

> This Canadian thriller features a cute little kid who kills. Connie and Linda give birth simultaneously in the same hospital. A mix up with the babies occur. Linda, after the baby, Adam, hits her, feels something is wrong. Indeed, the babe's real mother is a homicidal maniac and her illness seems to be genetic. [...] His parents really love him, but they are concerned. They should be. It is not long before bodies are dropping like flies in the house. [...] Eventually the mix-up is discovered and Linda confronts Connie, who is chained up in prison. Soon she discovers the whereabouts of her real son.

One of the victims is a kid who bullied Adam and the real killer is Adam's biological father who's been hiding in their attic. He tries to kill Linda but Adam shoots him and saves her. Here's the trailer: